# non continuous ivt problem

Tags: real-analysis, functions

solving for an ivt for a non-continuous function

We take $f : [0,1] \to [0,1]$  a non-increasing function, such that $f(x)≥ f(y)$ whenever $x≤ y$;

and we want to prove that there exists $c\in [0,1]$ such that $f(c) + c = 1$.

We let $A = \{ x \in [0,1] : f(x) + x  \ge 1\}$ and we define $c = \inf A$.

---

(a) explain why $c$ exists

(b) let $x_n$ be a sequence of elements of $A$ that converges to $c$, prove that for all $n, f(c) + x_n \ge 1$

(c) deduce that $f(c) + c \ge 1$

(d) if $c = 0$ prove that $f(c) + c \le 1$

(e) if $c \gt 0$, consider $x_n = c - 1/n$ prove that $f(c) + c \le 1$

---

### sorry for the bad formatting, i've changed it all around now -

Hi, I have been having trouble solving this question since the only information i could find online was using the IVT properties. Apparently this question should be solved without using the properties.

I just need help and some direction on where to go next. I am really stuck. Thank you in advance!

For b) would it be right to say that

Let c= inf A. Let n be any positive integer. Then a + 1/n is not an upper bound of S, so there is some a_n ∈ S with  a+1/n ≥ a_n >a. Then we can say the sequence (a_n) converges to a?

then we say since we have shown that f(c) + c = 1 (from boywholived) and that c = inf A, since x_n are elements of A, x_n>c
....and im kinda stuck here

Comment: You post needs massive formatting, to make it clear what you are asking about. I also believe that you are missing several conditions. For example, $f(x) = -1$ satisfies the conditions that I think I can find (unless positivity is thrown in there somewhere).

Comment: I have tried to format you post.  Please see if I did it right.  It takes two returns to get one on this site.  You can get some intro to $\LaTeX$ [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).  In b, should $x_n$ be $c_n$?

Comment: I think you might be missing part of the problem. You have to show $A$ is non-empty, and that's not clear. For instance, if $f(x) = -x$, then $f$ would be non-increasing, but $A$ would be empty.

Comment: I have pretty much copied the question I have word for word. How do I show that A is non empty?

Comment: You wrote "$f:[0,1]$"; this notation is not quite right. Can you double-check the question and see exactly how that part is written? That would be very helpful.

Comment: Sorry I have just edited that part! :) I'm double checking for more errors now but I think it is the question

Comment: Much better! So to start, we know $1 \in A$ because $f(x) + x = f(x) + 1 \geq 1$.

Comment: What else in particular are you having trouble with?

Comment: I am still working on it as we speak, flipping through my text book furiously and I am just really stumped. I feel as if b) and c) are just applications of limit definitions (which I haven't been able to find yet) Woould you be able to please provide me with some direction? :)

Comment: b) and c) actually have nothing to do with limits or continuity. As a hint for b), the $x_n$ are in $A$, which tells you something about $f(x_n) + x_n$, and remember that $c$ is the infimum of $A$ and that $f$ is a non-increasing function.

Comment: I have given b) a shot in my question, could you please assist me with more help if I am wrong please? :) thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit unclear, I only fully understood it now.

---

$\Large{\text{Question}}$

Let $f(x)$ be a function defined in the domain $\left[0,1\right]$, not necessarily continuous. Which satisfies the following conditions

1. $f(x)$ is non-increasing
2. The range is $\left[0,1\right]$
3. $f(x)+x \ge 1 \forall \quad x\; \in [0,1]$

**Prove that:**

1. There exist a $c\in [0,1]$ such that $f(c)+c=1$

---

**Solution.**

As the range is $\left[0,1\right]$
$$0\le f(x)\le 1\quad  \forall \quad x\in [0,1] \color{blue}{\star}$$
Using at $x=0$ using $3$ we get.
$f(0)+0\ge 1 \Rightarrow f(0)\ge 1$

But $f(0)\le 1$(Using$\color{blue}{\star}$)

Which implies $\boxed{f(0)=1}$
Then obviously a $c$ exist and $c=0$ the condition $f(c)+c=1$ is satisfied

Comment: Hope now everything is clear!.

Comment: Thank you! That's very clear and I fully understand it now :) Would you be able to please provide me feedback for my answer to b) and c) please? Thank you :)

Comment: Well, regarding $c$ isn't it a **given** statement in the question?. And for me $b$ and $c$ looks the same?. isn't it?.

Comment: Yeah, I think b and c are essentially the same - I have given an arguement for b) in my question - would you please be able to tell me if i am on the right track?